# Sequelize include with two where condition from two tables

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am a new one working in **Sequelize**. I do not know how to change the query to sequelize

```
SELECT a.* FROM employees a,emp_dept_details b where b.Dept_Id=2 AND a.Emp_No = b.Emp_Id
```

`Emp_No` is Primary Key in `Employee` table

```
EmpDeptDetails.hasMany(Emp, {foreignKey: 'Emp_No'})

Emp.belongsTo(EmpDeptDetails, {foreignKey: 'Emp_No'})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but try out the below query

Assuming

- You have the relationships between the 2 tables defined in the models class.
- You have Model `Employee` for `employees` table and `EmployeeDeptDetails` for `emp_dept_details` table. Change them to your respective names before trying.

```
 Employee.findAll({
   include: [{
     model: EmployeeDeptDetails,
     where: { Emp_Id: Sequelize.col('employees.Emp_No'), Dept_Id: 2 }
   }]
 });
```